# Mimic this groovy behavior in scala

Tags: scala, groovy

I have this function in groovy

```
def tokens = ['Will', 'is', 'coding', 'in', 'groovy']
String sentence = tokens.inject({sent, word -> sent + ' ' + word})
println sentence
```

with this output:

> "Will is coding in groovy"

Inject is to groovy as fold is to scala. If you do not set the accumulator value in inject, it defaults to the first item in the list. How can I do that in Scala?

```
val tokens = List("Will", "is", "coding", "in", "Scala")
val sentence = tokens.foldLeft(""){(sent, word) => sent + " " + word}
println(sentence)
```

produces this output (preceding space before the sentence):

> " Will is coding in Scala"

I get why it happens, but I'm not sure how I would eliminate it while still folding in this similar manner. Anyway to do this in Scala?

Comment: Why aren't you use `mkString` in this case?

Comment: This isn't for a real project. It's just for playing around with the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper equivalent of `inject` is `reduce` (actually I just noticed that you passed an initial value to `inject`, so this isn't entirely accurate—I'm not enough of a Groovy person to say why the Groovy version works without knowing what the value of `sent` is):

```
scala> val sentence = tokens.reduce { (sent, word) => sent + " " + word }
sentence: String = Will is coding in Scala
```

Note that this will blow up if `tokens` is empty. `reduceOption` is safer if there's any chance of that—it'll return a `None` if the collection is empty and a `Some[Whatever]` otherwise.

Comment: So if you do not provide an initial value, inject uses the first item in the list. You could provide an initial value which would make inject just like fold

Answer (score 1):

`mkString` exists exactly for this use case.

```
scala> val tokens = List("Will", "is", "coding", "in", "Scala") 
tokens: List[String] = List("Will", "is", "coding", "in", "Scala")
scala> tokens.mkString(" ") 
res1: String = "Will is coding in Scala"
```